# php api Unauthorized request json rpc 2.0

Tags: php, api, json-rpc

I want to access api with my api key that is correct but still geting back error 401 unauthorized.
Api using json rpc 2.0.

This is example request from api docs.

```
Request:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "getBoards",
  "params": {
       "clientId": "apikey"
 },
 "id": 1
}
```

And this is my php code.

```
$apiKey = 'apikey';
$apiUrl = 'apiUrl';

$data =  array(
        "jsonrpc" => "2.0",
        "method" => "getBoards",
        "params" => array(
            "clientId" => $apiKey
        ),
        "id" => "1"
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey my client made a mistake and api key was wrong so at least this is the correct way how to use php with protocol jsonrpc 2.0